# how to Calculate the cost of user anger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a calculator to calculate the cost of anger.

I don't really know how to explain but I will try my best to explain the problem, so i want user to put there Age Salary hours per day of work, how many time they have anger at work, and how long does it last.

I have formula in excel file (if you're good enough you will understand ) and some code that i try make. 
Here is the link of Excel file and code __

You might need to check out the excel file to understand what I mean (I'm so sorry that I cant explain to you clearly cos my English is really poor I'm really sorry.)
https://drive.google.com/open…

I also have Html and Java script code that I tried to writ; (I need to delete some code in order to let stack over flow let me show the code)
Thank you very much guys

Html

```
<div class="login">
<form method="post">
    <p> Enter your age </p>
        <input id="user_age" type="text" name="a" value="0" required="required" />
    <p>Enter your salary or income ($) </p>
        <input id="user_salary" type="text" name="b" value="0" required="required" />
    <p> Enter Work hours per day </p>
        <input id="user_work" type="text" name="x" value="0" required="required" />
    <p> How often do you get angry per day during work.</p>
        <input id="user_time" type="text" name="c" value="0" required="required" />
    <p> How many hours does the average anger last? </p>
        <input id="user_anger" type="text" name="d" value="0" required="required" />        
    <p id="results"></p>

    <input type="button" class="button" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Java Scipt code

```
function calcAnger () {
var sixty = 60;
var age = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_age').value);
var salary = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_salary').value);
var workTime = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_work').value);    
var angerDay = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_time').value);
var angerLast = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_anger').value);
var calculate = "Your cost of anger: $" + ' ' + age * salary* 243 * workTime * angerDay * angerLast * 2;

document.getElementById ('results').innerHTML = calculate;
return false;
calculate.style.color = "#ff0000";
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine; you were just missing an event handler on your button.  I added one inline (`onClick="calcAnger()"`).  There are a handful of ways to add that but I just gave the the quick option based on the small code sample you provided.

```js
function calcAnger() {
  var age = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_age').value);
  var salary = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_salary').value);
  var workTime = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_work').value);
  var angerDay = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_time').value);
  var angerLast = parseFloat(document.getElementById('user_anger').value);
  var calculate = "Your cost of anger: $" + ' ' + age * salary * 243 * workTime * angerDay * angerLast * 2;

  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <form method="post">
    <p> Enter your age </p>
    <input id="user_age" type="text" name="a" value="0" required="required" />
    <p>Enter your salary or income ($) </p>
    <input id="user_salary" type="text" name="b" value="0" required="required" />
    <p> Enter Work hours per day </p>
    <input id="user_work" type="text" name="x" value="0" required="required" />
    <p> How often do you get angry per day during work.</p>
    <input id="user_time" type="text" name="c" value="0" required="required" />
    <p> How many hours does the average anger last? </p>
    <input id="user_anger" type="text" name="d" value="0" required="required" />
    <p id="results"></p>

    <input type="button" class="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calcAnger()">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply change some semantics in your HTML code and take the advantage of FORM tag. Using the below approach you may apply validations too in your form before submitting. Will let you know those details if you want.

```
  <script>
      function calcAnger() {
        var age = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loginForm").a.value);
          var salary = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loginForm").b.value);
          var workTime = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loginForm").x.value);
          var angerDay = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loginForm").c.value);
          var angerLast = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loginForm").d.value);
          var calculate = "Your cost of anger: $" + ' ' + age * salary * 243 * workTime * angerDay * angerLast * 2;

          document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = calculate;
        }
    </script>   
<div class="login" >
    <form method="post" onSubmit="calcAnger()" id="loginForm">
        <p> Enter your age </p>
            <input id="user_age" type="text" name="a" value="0" required="required" />
        <p>Enter your salary or income ($) </p>
            <input id="user_salary" type="text" name="b" value="0" required="required" />
        <p> Enter Work hours per day </p>
            <input id="user_work" type="text" name="x" value="0" required="required" />
        <p> How often do you get angry per day during work.</p>
            <input id="user_time" type="text" name="c" value="0" required="required" />
        <p> How many hours does the average anger last? </p>
            <input id="user_anger" type="text" name="d" value="0" required="required" />        
        <p id="results"></p>

        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Calculate">
    </form>
    </div>
```